# XAMPP Magento var director

Tags: magento, directory, xampp, localhost, var

I am facing the following error in my `magento localhost`. I have tried creating a `tmp` folder in the root directory but that is not working. Thanks

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFbvV.png]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sure if it means I'll get an answer there.
Thank you